# On Integral consisting $\sin^2(f(x))$:

Tags: integration, analysis, definite-integrals, asymptotics, trigonometric-integrals

Consider the following integral:

$$I(t)=\int_1^t\sin^2(f(x))dx$$

Here , $f(x)$ is monotonic for the given domain and is at least twice differentiable.

> Is there a result (in its full generality) of following type exists :
>
> $I(x)= g(x)+O(j(x))$

Such that , $j(x)$ is bounded and g(x) is monotonic .

Comment: Welcome to MSE. What have you tried? The community doesn't like this website being used as a homework machine.

Comment: @AryanSonwatikar this is not a homework question; I worked on some special cases for $f$. The question is just a curiosity for generality.

Comment: $I(x)$ is itself is increasing . So you can take $g=I$ and $j=0$.